# Django REST Framework, limiting fields on foreignkey relationship when serializer depth = 1

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using the Django REST Framework and I have a serializer as follows:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        depth = 1
        fields = ['user','team','correct','wrong','percentage']
```

The problem if this passes all `user` data (including a hashed password).  How do I limit the fields being passed?

I have a UserSerializer as follows (which holds the only fields I really want):

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','username']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `depth` option declare `user` field explicitly in `UserProfileSerializer` and use `UserSerializer` for this field:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['user','team','correct','wrong','percentage']
```

Or try to override [`build_nested_field`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#build_nested_fieldself-field_name-relation_info-nested_depth) like this:

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        depth = 1
        fields = ['user','team','correct','wrong','percentage']

    def build_nested_field(self, field_name, relation_info, nested_depth):
        if field_name == 'user': 
            field_class = UserSerializer
            field_kwargs = get_nested_relation_kwargs(relation_info)

            return field_class, field_kwargs
        return super().build_nested_field(field_name, relation_info, nested_depth)
```